# Get start and end indices of longest streak of repetitions in a list

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I'm putting together something where I want to show the longest streak of wins of a team and the start and end date of this particular streak. So for example, if I have the following two lists:

```
streak = ["W", "W", "W", "L","W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "L"]
dates =  ["2016-06-15", "2016-06-14", "2016-06-13", "2016-06-10", "2016-06-09", "2016-06-08", "2016-06-05", "2016-06-03", "2016-06-02", "2016-06-02"]
```

Then if I wanted to get the longest streak I could do something like:

```
from itertools import groupby
longest = sorted([list(y) for x, y in groupby(streak)], key = len)[-1]
print longest
["W", "W", "W", "W", "W"]
```

Now my idea was (let me know if this can be done better) to somehow get the start and end indices of this longest streak, so in this case:

```
start, end = get_indices(streak, longest) # 8, 4
print "The longest streak of {}{} was from {} to {}.".format(len(longest), longest[0], dates[start], dates[end])
"The longest streak of 5W was from 2016-06-02 to 2016-06-09.
```

How can I do this? Or is there a better way to do this, for example zipping the lists together and doing something with that?

Comment: just to mention your dates are "inversed" from the end of the list to the begining ... I took this into account in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking into account your code, you can still go ahead with `itertools` and use the underdog `takewhile`:

```
from itertools import takewhile, groupby
import itertools

L = [list(y) for x, y in groupby(streak)]
l = sorted(L, key=len)[-1]

ix = len(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(takewhile(lambda x: x!=l, L))))

print("the longest streak goes from " + dates[ix+len(l)] + " to " + dates[ix])
#the longest streak goes from 2016-06-02 to 2016-06-09
```

Comment: A couple notes: 1. You need to use `dates[ix+len(l)-1]` (note added `-1`) or you overshoot the end date (you don't notice this on sample data because sample data repeats the same date at the end of one streak and the beginning of the next, but if dates were unique, it would be wrong). 2. Naming variables `L` and especially `l` is really maintainer hostile, makes it hard to distinguish the variable name from the constant `int` `1`, the name `I` (capital i), or the bitwise or operatior `|`, depending on font.

Comment: Curious if you would know of a way to find the longest "W" stream _and_ the longest "L" streak? Because they could both be the same length and I'd like to check that.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solutions that reduce temporaries (but note, unless seriously RAM constrained or generating unreasonably huge streaks, generating the temporaries is faster than minimal temporary alternatives). Not necessary, just illustrating other way to combine iterator related tools to achieve the same result:

```
from itertools import groupby, tee, zip_longest
from operator import itemgetter, sub

def longeststreak(streaks, dates):
    # Create parallel iterators over the first index of each new group
    s, e = tee(map(next, map(itemgetter(1), groupby(range(len(streaks)), key=streaks.__getitem__))))
    # Advance end iterator so we can zip at offset to create start/end index pairs
    next(e, None)
    # Find greatest difference between start and end
    longend, longstart = max(zip_longest(e, s, fillvalue=len(streaks)), key=lambda es: sub(*es))
    # return dates for those indices (must subtract one from end since end index is exclusive)
    return dates[longend-1], dates[longstart]
```

Or another approach:

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter, sub

def longeststreak(streaks, dates):
    # Generator of grouped indices for each streak
    streakgroups = map(itemgetter(1), groupby(range(len(streaks)), streaks.__getitem__))
    # Get first and last index of each streak without storing intermediate indices
    streakranges = ((next(iter(deque(g, 1)), start), start) for g in streakgroups for start in (next(g),))
    # As before, find greatest difference and return range
    longend, longstart = max(streakranges, key=lambda es: sub(*es))
    # End index is inclusive in this design, so don't subtract 1
    return dates[longend], dates[longstart]
```

In both cases, if on Py2, you'll need to import `map` from `future_builtins`, and for the former, use `izip_longest`.

Also, just for completeness, the optimized version of [Colonel Beauvel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37860181/364696) to minimize byte code execution (slow in CPython) in favor of more C level execution (fast in CPython):

```
def longeststreak(streaks, dates):
    # Use map with C-level builtins to reduce bytecode use
    streakgroups = list(map(list, map(itemgetter(1), groupby(streaks))))
    # Use max with key instead of sorted followed by indexing at -1, to turn
    # O(n log n) work into O(n) work
    longeststreak = max(streakgroups, key=len)
    # Replace lambda with C layer built-in comparator
    ix = len(list(chain.from_iterable(takewhile(longeststreak.__ne__, streakgroups))))
    # Added -1 missing in original answer; end index should be exclusive,
    # so we need to subtract 1; not noticeable on sample data because sample
    # data had same data at end of longest streak and beginning of next
    return dates[ix+len(longeststreak)-1], dates[ix]
```

For the record, thanks to various bits of overhead involved in trying to avoid creating `list`/`tuple`s containing the whole streak as a group, when we only need start and end, my two alternate solutions run slower on basically all real world data; a test case involving randomish streak lengths, with a total of 450K entries, on `ipython3` (Python 3.5 x86-64 for Linux), on my machine took about 35 ms to process with the optimized version of the Colonel's answer, ~50 ms with my first, `tee` using solution, and ~77 ms with my second, `deque` using solution.

Comment: Curious if you would know of a way to find the longest "W" stream _and_ the longest "L" streak?